# Find the intersection of two line when have two array of points

Tags: c#

```
PointF[] points1;
PointF[] points2;
_Gd.DrawLines(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Purple)),points1);
_Gd.DrawLines(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Green)),points2);
```

Above code use to draw two line, I want to find all the intersection  of two line above, how can I do that in C#? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: This might help: http://paulbourke.net/geometry/lineline2d/

Comment: @ObaidR thank for your link but I don't understand exactly, your link will find one intersection of 2 line (with 4 point) but mine is all intersection of 2 line (two array of points) how can I do that?

Comment: You should intersect each segment of the first array with each segment of the second array.